# Calculating heat leak in a cryostat

Tags: experimental-physics, low-temperature-physics

I'd like to optimise a cryostat insert. It will be used for resistance measurements at around $4.2K$. I'm having a little trouble getting started with my constraints. I need to calculate the largest amount of heat leak that would be acceptable, given that the largest possible boil-off rate of  $^4$He is 50ml per hour. So how much heat can be allowed to leak into the helium? I'm assuming it involves Fourier's law for heat flow Q:

$$Q = \frac{A}{L}(T_2-T_1)\bar{K}$$

I have a table of values for $\bar{K}$ for different materials in different temperature changes, so if someone could give me a hand with the method I can do the calculation.

I don't know what $L$ will be yet. Around the $1$m mark hopefully. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is not quite as easy as just one equation.  
Having a vacuum between the walls of a cryostat will reduce losses due to conduction and convection but as many materials, including glass, are porous to Helium gas there is a need of continuous pumping.  
Radiation is going to contribute significantly and that is why cryostats within cryostats are used to reduce the temperature gradient.  
So one might have liquid Nitrogen between the liquid Helium and the outside world. You need to search the literature. THis is a reasonable summary http://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/10MIT/Lecture_5.1.pdf

Comment: @Farcher Radiation I will of course consider radiation as well, I expect losses through residual gas conduction to be minimal because of a high-quality vacuum, but initially then could I ignore from which contributions the heat leak comes and use something like $Q=mC\Delta T$ to calculate the heat that would lead to the $50ml/hr$ boil off? I'm not quite sure how I'd actually perform that calculation, but something along those lines.